# В чем разница между visibility:collapse и display:none?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В чем разница между `visibility:collapse` и `display:none`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695813

Comment: там на английском, не владею

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Первый используется, чтобы полностью скрыть элементы таблицы. Последний используется, чтобы полностью скрыть все остальное.

---

`visibility: collapse` полностью скрывает элемент (чтобы он не занимал никакого пространства в макете), но только когда [элемент является элементом таблицы](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility).

Если используется для элементов, отличных от элементов таблицы, `visibility: collapse` будет действовать как `visibility: hidden`. Это делает элемент невидимым, но он все равно будет занимать место в макете.

`display: none` полностью скрывает элемент, поэтому он не занимает места в макете, но его не следует использовать в элементах таблицы.

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility)

---

**[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695813/difference-between-visibilitycollapse-and-displaynone)**

Answer (score 0):

Если `visibility:collapse` применяется не к строкам или колонкам таблицы, то результат его использования будет таким же, как `visibility:hidden`. В случае использования `visibility:collapse` для содержимого ячеек таблиц, то они реагируют, словно к ним было добавлено `display: none`. Иными словами, заданные строки и колонки убираются, а таблица перестраивается по новой. Это значение не поддерживается браузером Internet Explorer.